# Could not set secondary tile in window phone8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I tried for setting up secondary tile for my app from link:  http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/how-to-add-and-remove-secondary-tiles-in-windows-phone-apps . Then I could set up the secondary tile pinned to the start up menu, but the problem is that when I pressed the pin application bar button, it broke to the code handle exception like this

```
  // Code to execute on Unhandled Exceptions
        private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
                Debugger.Break();
            }
        }
```

Secondary Tile was created to the start up menu, but when I clicked it, it could not resume to the pinned page.

What I suspected are that some data used on the pinned page were dependant on the data sent from the previouse page; therefore,it doesn't have enough data when it was navigated to it directly from the start menu. Am I correct?

Here my page that I want to pin it to the start up menu:

```
namespace App_Skin_Test_Final_.All_Files.Product_Files
{
    public partial class Product_Detail : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        string pro_name;
        string pro_image;
        string pro_ingridient;
        //string pro_link;
        string pro_use;
        string pro_dryDesc1;
        string pro_dryDesc2;
        // ImageSource image;

        private readonly string SecondaryTileUriSource = "Source=SecondaryTile";

        public Product_Detail()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            // =====================================   Add Search application bar   =====================================
            // Show application bar
            ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
            ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Default;
            ApplicationBar.Opacity = 1.0;
            ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
            ApplicationBar.IsMenuEnabled = true;

            // Search Application bar
            ApplicationBarIconButton btnSearch = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
            btnSearch.IconUri = new Uri("/images/Icon Application Bars/Search.png", UriKind.Relative);
            btnSearch.Text = "Search";
            ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(btnSearch);
            btnSearch.Click += btnSearch_Click;

            ApplicationBarIconButton btnPin = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
            btnPin.IconUri = new Uri("/images/Icon Application Bars/pin.png", UriKind.Relative);
            btnPin.Text = "Pin";
            ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(btnPin);

            btnPin.Click += btnPin_Click;

        }

        void btnPin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          // secondary tile can be created only as the result
          // of user input in an application

            ShellTile tile = this.FindTile(SecondaryTileUriSource);
            if(tile==null)
            {
                //because the UI will navigate to Start
                //When a new secondary tile is created
                //only one secondary tile can be created at a time
                StandardTileData tileData = this.GetSecondaryTileData();

                MessageBox.Show("The SecondaryTileUriSource is " + SecondaryTileUriSource);

                //having a unique NavigationUri is necessary for distinguishing this tile
               string tileUri = string.Concat("/All Files/Product Files/Dry/Product Detail.xmal?", SecondaryTileUriSource);

             //   MessageBox.Show("the uri is " + tileUri);
               ShellTile.Create(new Uri(tileUri, UriKind.Relative), tileData);

            }
        }
        // function Search application bar
        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/All Files/Product Files/Search.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            // Check if the Secondar tile exists 

            ShellTile secondaryTile = this.FindTile(SecondaryTileUriSource);

            if (secondaryTile != null)
            {

         // *****************************************************      tile.Delete();
                MessageBox.Show("Secondary tile exist.");
            }



            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("pro_name", out pro_name))
            {

            }
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("pro_image", out pro_image))
            {

            }
            txtbPro_Name.Text = pro_name;

            BitmapImage bm = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["myimage"] as BitmapImage;
            img_Product.Source = bm;

            // Ingridient Text
            pro_ingridient = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["ItemDryIngridient"] as string;
            txtb_ingridient.Text = pro_ingridient;
            // Find on Somaly store
            //pro_link = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["ItemDryLink"] as String;
            //txtb_link = pro_link;


            // How to use product
            pro_use = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["ItemDryUse"] as string;
            txtb_howToUse.Text = pro_use;

            // Description 1 and Description 2
            pro_dryDesc1 = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["ItemDryDesc1"] as string;
            txtb_description1.Text = pro_dryDesc1;
            pro_dryDesc2 = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["ItemDryDesc2"] as string;
            txtb_description2.Text = pro_dryDesc2;



            // txtb_ingridient.Text = pro_image;
            // image = getImage(pro_image);
            // MessageBox.Show(image);
            // img_Product.Source = image;



        }

        private ImageSource getImage(string img)
        {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri(img, UriKind.Relative));
        }



        /*********************************************
         * Create a Secondary Tile for pin application
         *********************************************/

        private StandardTileData GetSecondaryTileData()
        {
            StandardTileData titleData = new StandardTileData
            {
                Title = "Secondary Tile",
                BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Images/Allures/Base/aba001.jpg", UriKind.Relative),
                Count = 5,
                BackTitle = "Secondary Tile",
                BackgroundImage = new Uri("", UriKind.Relative),
                BackContent = "WPG Add Remove Tile Sample"
            };
            return titleData;
        }
        private ShellTile FindTile(string partOfUri)
        {
            ShellTile shellTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(
                title => title.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains(partOfUri));
            return shellTile;
        }




    }
}
```

How could I correct it work fine? or are there something else I'm missing in my app?

Comment: Try to put breakpoint at `Product_Detail` constructor, step line by line and see if any obvious error occur. In general, try to get a specific error message

Comment: Exactly what is the target of your application? Windows Phone 8.0, Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight or Windows Phone 8.1 XAML? Setting a secondary tile is different depending on that.

Comment: I set the application minimum target to Windows Phone 8.0

Comment: har07, sorry for late reply. I put break point at Product_Detail constructor and step over line by line from the biginning to the end, and here I got the error message like this **InvalidDataContractException was unhandled. Additional information: Type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want to serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. Alternatively, you can ensure that the type is public and has a parameterless constructor - all public members of the type...**

Comment: Is this code copy and paste from your app? Because I see the URI set as "/All Files/Product Files/Dry/Product Detail.xmal" - note the typo xmal instead of xaml - it may be a reason why the app does not navigate to the correct page

Comment: Sorry my mistake :), I corrected that to /All Files/Product Files/Dry/Product Detail.xaml already, however, the same problem still persists with the error message like above. Anyway when I click on secondary tile at the start, it just show Resuming... but does not show the page

Comment: Have you tried to use the exactly same uri (/All Files/Product Files/Dry/Product Detail.xaml?Source=SecondaryTile) from inside the application, for example in the btnSearch_Click() function?

Comment: No, I could not navigate to that uri ("All Files/Product Files/Dry/Product Detail.xaml?Source=SecondaryTile") as I tested. It showed the error at `BitmapImage bm = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["myimage"] as BitmapImage;` with the message **KeyNotFoundException was unhandled by user code: The given key was not present in the dictionary**. How can I correct this error?

Comment: @user2273145 So, the problem is not at all in the secondary tile, but in saving and restoring state for that page. I guess you try to store a bitmap in the page state dictionary and that may not be supported. You may store a bitmap in the app data folder, and in the page state save the name of the bitmap

Comment: Now I found the error with this uri ("All Files/Product Files/Dry/Product Detail.xaml?Source=SecondaryTile"). The error is at every line of PhoneApplicationService.Current.State. If I comment all of them out, the page is showed, but it is a blank page; I don't want it like this :(. In deed, I use PhoneApplicationService.Current.State for storing the selected items data that user selects from the list box in the previous page "Product List.xaml" to send to this page "Product Detail.xaml" for it to show user. How can I do?

Comment: All data on the page "Product Detail.xaml" is showed as normal if I navigate to it page by page, from Product List.xaml to Product Detail.xaml.

Comment: @user2273145 Please post a new question about the state, including the code that you use to save and restore the state

Comment: ok, thanks. I will post a new question that related to the state save and store information, and how to call it back directly from the secondary Tile.

Comment: @user2273145 side note: next time use `@` at the beginning of the user name to get the user notified about your comment

Comment: @har07, well noticed